# How do I extend this Ruby module?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to utilise the [Gmail](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail) gem in a gem that I'm building. From [the source](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail/blob/master/lib/gmail.rb#L18), you can see that the gem defines the Gmail module/class like so (simplified):

```
module Gmail
  class <<  self
    def connect; end
  end
end
```

What I would like to do is to extend the Gmail module/class into a class of my own. Essentially, this is a generic example of what I'm trying to do:

```
module Foo 
  class << self
    def example
      puts :this_is_foo
    end 
  end 
end

class Bar
  extend Foo
end
```

Then I should be able to call:

```
Bar.example
```

But I get the following exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `example' for Bar:Class
```

How do I make methods that are available in `Foo` available in `Bar` in the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `included` for your goal:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def example
      puts :this_is_foo
    end 
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

Bar.example
this_is_foo
#=> nil
```

Or if you want to include only class methods, you can make your `example` method instance and extend `Bar` module:

```
module Foo
  def example
    puts :this_is_foo
  end 
end
class Bar
  extend Foo
end
Bar.example
this_is_foo
#=> nil
```

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea what that's doing! Whilst this answers the question that I asked, it doesn't allow me to extend the Gmail class that I set about extending in the first place. The example code works, though so I'd class this as answered and I'll ask a more specific question about the Gmail gem.